# grails load() method does not return a proxy instance

Tags: hibernate, grails, proxy

Environment: **grails 2.0.1**

i have a simple domain entity:

```
class Author {
 String name

 static hasMany = [books : Book]
```

}

and im trying to load a proxy of id 1

```
def auth = Author.load(1)
```

However, as i can see from the console sql log, a query is executed that fetches a non-proxy instance of the Author! Why does it work like this? And how can i load a proxy instance?

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
def author = Author.get(1)
```

or a read-only instance:

```
def author = Aughor.read(1)
```